# How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and simply want to get the element at index 1.

```js
var myValues = new Array();
var valueAtIndex1 = myValues.getValue(1); // (something like this)
```

How can I get the value at the 1st index of my array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You can access an element at a specific index using the bracket notation accessor.

```js
var valueAtIndex1 = myValues[1];
```

On newer browsers/JavaScript engines ([see browser compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility)), you can also use the `.at()` method on arrays.

```js
var valueAtIndex1 = myValues.at(1);
```

On positive indexes, both methods work the same (the first one being more common). `Array.prototype.at()` however allows you to access elements starting from the end of the array by passing a negative number. Passing `-1` will give the last element of the array, passing `-2` the second last, etc.

See more details at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).

Comment: This returns the element at the second index not at the "1st" as specified in the question.

Comment: The question says "get the element at index 1". Index 1 is the second element in the array.

Comment: I don't think indexer is an official term.. correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 45):

Array indexes in JavaScript start at zero for the first item, so try this:

```
var firstArrayItem = myValues[0]
```

Of course, if you actually want the second item in the array at index 1, then it's `myValues[1]`.

See [Accessing array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#accessing_array_elements) for more info.

Answer (score 15):

You can just use `[]`:

```
var valueAtIndex1 = myValues[1];
```

Answer (score 11):

**indexer** (`array[index]`) is the most frequent use. An alternative is `at` array method:

```
const cart = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
cart.at(0) // 'apple'
cart.at(2) // 'pear'
```

*If you come from another programming language, maybe it looks more familiar.*

Comment: Looks like the at method is very new/currently a proposal. It works in Chrome DevTools but not Edabit. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method

Answer (score 2):

### **Update 2022**

With ES2022 you can use `Array.prototype.at()`:

```js
const myValues = [1, 2, 3]
myValues.at(1) // 2
```

`at()` also supports negative index, which returns an **element from the end of** the array:

```js
const myValues = [1, 2, 3]
myValues.at(-1) // 3
myValues.at(-2) // 2
```

Read more:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), [JavascriptTutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-at/), [Specifications](https://tc39.es/proposal-relative-indexing-method/#sec-array-prototype-additions)

Answer (score 1):

`shift` can be used in places where you want to get the first element (`index=0`) of an array and chain with other array methods.

example:

```
const comps = [{}, {}, {}]
const specComp = comps
                  .map(fn1)
                  .filter(fn2)
                  .shift()
```

Remember `shift` mutates the array, which is very different from accessing via an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[];`

```
var indexValue = Index[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you specifically want to get the element at index 1. You can also achieve this by using Array destructuring from ES6.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const [zeroIndex, firstIndex, ...remaining] = arr;
console.log(firstIndex); // 2
```

Or, As per ES2022. You can also use `Array.at()`

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr.at(1)); // 2
```