# html forum and javascripty

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to get an text field text in to an array? Is it possible to get a text from text field and put it in to character array to select each Alphabet and use it in different places?

Like I have a words

```
Computer
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

I need it like in different Block Like Name Speel

```
[C] [o] [m] [p] [u] [t] [e] [r]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript string to array conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/javascript-string-to-array-conversion)

Comment: @APerson It isn't a duplicate, since it is splitting a string using a comma instead of an empty character.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Well, many of the answers there are about how to split on a random character, which is more or less the point of this question.

Comment: Who says it is duplicate i am asking for word "computer" in split them in to [c] [o] [m] [p] [u] [t] [e] [r] the main thing is break in to alphabets and in the form of blocks

Comment: i want to know that whether this type of function is available in JavaScript or not

Answer (score 2):

What you might want is the following JavaScript:

```
"Computer".split("")
```

Comment: But i want to split one words in to characters

Comment: how to read an specific alphabet from it. How to Access "p" from whole words....?

Comment: @user3857603 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem is this part: "select each Alphabet and use it in Different Places Like..." so the solution is to use .charAt() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "How are you doing today?";
    var res = str.charAt(0);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks This what i wanted. I searched about it but i did not found thanks once again my friend told me about this web site for Question not be found