# Checking individual elements in Array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
myArray={["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"] , ["Shaw"],["Help me help me"]}
```

I want to test the each array index content for repetition. 
For e.g: I want to take `myArray[0]` which is `["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"]`, and check if it contains repeated words. In this case the result is yes.

I am not getting how to check the individual at myArray[0]. How can I do it using javascript.

Comment: That isn't JavaScript code.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript

Comment: Do you need the checking to be done in javascript

Comment: `{...}` is not an array in JS (It's an object). Use `[...]` if you want to use it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your array is properly defined:

```
var myArray = [
  ["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"],
  ["Shaw"],
  ["Help me help me"]
];
```

Use a function that passes array elements into a temporary array, returning `false` if it finds no duplicates or `true` if it does.

```
function hasDuplicate(arr) {
  for (var dupe = [], i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var val = arr[i];
    if (dupe.indexOf(val) > -1) return true;
    if (val !== 0) dupe.push(val);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Loop over the array and check each nested array:

```
myArray.forEach(function(arr) {
  console.log(hasDuplicate(arr)); // true, false, false
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8cxm57r4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to do it like this. You can pass your arrays to this function and check for duplicates.

```
function(anArray) {

   var uniqueNames = [];

   $.each(anArray, function(i, el){
      if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) 
         uniqueNames.push(el);
      else
         return false;
  });

  return true; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function takes an array and dedupes it.  You can map through your original array and dedupe each individually.

```js
function hasDupe(arr) {
  var index = {};
  for (var i in arr) {
    if (!index[arr[i]]) {
      index[arr[i]] = true;
      continue;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question about deduping an array - it asks whether an array _has_ duplicates.

Comment: Adjusted... for that case

Comment: @Andy Sorry, made a mistake there fixed and tested working.  Checks for dupes now returns true if there is a dupe and false if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `indexOf()` equals `lastIndexOf()`.
If if does, that underlying element appears in the array more than once.

```
function isDup(list){
    // Return true if at least one element `n` appears more than once in `list`
    return list.some(function(n,i){
        return i != list.lastIndexOf(n) // i potentially equals list.indexOf(n)
    });
}

var list = ["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"];
isDup(list); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way: build up a map for each subarray, then evaluated the word frequencies for > 0 to make a duplication determination.

```
var ar = [["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"] , ["Shaw","Shaw"],["Help me help me"]];
var arrayIndex = 0;
ar.forEach(function(a) {
    var n = {};
    a.forEach(function(l) {
        n[l] = n[l] != undefined ? n[l] + 1 : 0;
    });
    Object.keys(n).forEach(function(k) {
        if (n[k] > 0) console.log("Array index", arrayIndex, "has repeated words.")
    })
    arrayIndex++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [
  ["Michael", "Michael", "Angelo"],
  ["Shaw"],
  ["Help me help me"],
];

function checkDuplicates(arr){
    arr.forEach(function(row){
            console.log('>>'+row + 'contains duplicate :');
            for(var i = 0, l = row.length, el = []; i<l; i++){
                if(el.indexOf(row[i])<0){
                    el.push(row[i]);
                }else{
                    console.log('\tyes')
                    return;
                }
            }
            console.log('\tno');
        }
    );



}

checkDuplicates(myArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can loop through the array and for each element check

```
Set(array[i])).size == array[i].length
```

if there are duplicates in each element this will return `false` at that iteration and then you should break the loop.