# How to get the specific object value when the object has no key?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

As you see the picture below, I have some data in a JSON but these values are not blinded with Key.

[image]

What is the best way to get the first element "Hang Seng Bank" only?

Rearrange the source data by myself?

Or assign Keys for values in JS?

Comment: you have the answers already

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to access the values as the keys seem to be numbered.

```js
var obj={
0:"bank",
1:"200",
2:"200"
}
console.log(obj[0])
```

`obj[0]` will give the output where obj is your JSON object

Answer (score 0):

The answer is accessed the value by something like

```
myArray[0][1]
```