# How to get the number data from second object in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, numbers

I want to get the data from the second object's tts number (1,152.81).
How should I point that data?

My js file below. Probably priceTag.innerHTML = data[0].tts isn't the right code for it. But I can't find how to grab that data.

```
const url = "https://www.koreaexim.go.kr/site/program/financial/exchangeJSON?authkey=KiGkSEG4nhXCrQ0PioaqVQJDb0lEfKeE&data=AP01"
const priceTag = document.querySelector("h1")

// grab data
const checkPrice = function() {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      priceTag.innerHTML = data[0].tts
    })
}

checkPrice()
```

In JASON file, there are 22 objects but I copied only 2 of them.

```
[
{
"result": 1,
"cur_unit": "THB",
"ttb": "35.42",
"tts": "36.13",
"deal_bas_r": "35.78",
"bkpr": "35",
"yy_efee_r": "0",
"ten_dd_efee_r": "0",
"kftc_bkpr": "35",
"kftc_deal_bas_r": "35.78",
},
{
"result": 1,
"cur_unit": "USD",
"ttb": "1,129.98",
"tts": "1,152.81",
"deal_bas_r": "1,141.4",
"bkpr": "1,141",
"yy_efee_r": "0",
"ten_dd_efee_r": "0",
"kftc_bkpr": "1,141",
"kftc_deal_bas_r": "1,141.4",
}
]
```

Comment: data[1] ??? yu should be using

Comment: If you want to print second object's data in your price tag then use: `priceTag.innerHTML = data[1].tts;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try data[1] or not? Your data now is an array with each element is an object

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
    "result": 1,
    "cur_unit": "THB",
    "ttb": "35.42",
    "tts": "36.13",
    "deal_bas_r": "35.78",
    "bkpr": "35",
    "yy_efee_r": "0",
    "ten_dd_efee_r": "0",
    "kftc_bkpr": "35",
    "kftc_deal_bas_r": "35.78",
  },
  {
    "result": 1,
    "cur_unit": "USD",
    "ttb": "1,129.98",
    "tts": "1,152.81",
    "deal_bas_r": "1,141.4",
    "bkpr": "1,141",
    "yy_efee_r": "0",
    "ten_dd_efee_r": "0",
    "kftc_bkpr": "1,141",
    "kftc_deal_bas_r": "1,141.4",
  }
]

console.log(data[1].tts)
```