# How to select value inside array

Tags: javascript

This the code in the var named available_dates

`var available_dates = ["08-11-2018","09-11-2018"]`

I wonder how can I choose the second date of the var and selected, to my second code

`document.getElementById('app_date').value = available_dates`

Comment: Are you asking how to perform array index access?

Comment: `available_dates[1]`

Comment: I can't even find a suitable duplicate of this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json  is a duplicate, but so is google.

Comment: @Taplar that's far too complicated for this question...  something like this is more appropriate in my opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah, I would agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply access array by its key `available_dates[1]`

```js
function getDate() {
  var available_dates = ["08-11-2018","09-11-2018"]  
  document.getElementById("myText").value = available_dates[1];
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">

<button onclick="getDate()">Get Date</button>
```

Link for javascript array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thanks ....but what if var available_dates was in another script not in the same function , how to detecte the value !!

Comment: hi see in any language if you want to access a variable it should be declared before it's use so if the variable is in another script file than include that file before this function is being called and than use that variable

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access a value in your array available_dates by doing this:

```
document.getElementById('app_date').value = available_dates[i]
```

Be careful to the fact that indexes start from 0. so available_dates[0] will return the first index. available_dates[1] will return the second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

U must indicate which position of the array u want:

`document.getElementById('app_date').value = available_dates[1]`

Be happy!!