# Javascript dynamic programming table, can't index 2D array like in Python in some cases?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

Edit: Actually the logic is wrong here.
I solved it using Python3 with a dictionary that updates the last index at which a letter is seen.  In dynamic programming lingo, it is similar to L.I.S (longest increasing subsequence).

If anyone knows how to solve this without using a dictionary, please comment because I learned DP in school and those lessons only used arrays so it should be possible with just arrays.

Original question:

I am trying Leetcode, 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.

I can solve this in Python making a 2D table for dynamic programming.

But in JavaScript which I am sort of new to, I am getting an error.

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:41
                var top = T[i-1][j]
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at lengthOfLongestSubstring (evalmachine.<anonymous>:4
```

My code:

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {number}
 */
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    //empty string
    if (s.length <= 0){
        return 0
    }
    //initialize dict
    var dict = {};
    //initialize 2D table T
    var T = new Array(s.length)
    for (var i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        T[i] = new Array(s.length);
    }
    
    //base cases are diagonals
    for (var i = 0; i < T.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<T.length; j++){
            if(i==j){
                T[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                T[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //put base case in dict
    //dict[s[0]]=1
    for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++){
        for (var j=i+1; j<s.length; j++){
            var row_char = s.charAt(i);
            var col_char = s.charAt(j);
            if (row_char==col_char){
                T[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                //console.log("j",j,T)
                var left = T[i][j-1]
                console.log(left)
                var top = T[i-1][j] 
                console.log(top)
                var bigger = Math.max(left,top);
                T[i][j] = bigger + 1
            }
        }
    }
    //iterate each row to get max
    var high = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        if(T[i][s.length-1] > high){
            high = T[i][s.length-1];
        } 
    }
    
    return high;
    
};
```

It is letting me fill the table with 0's and base case of 1 indexing like `T[i][j]` but then complaining about indexing like that to get the value which I don't understand.

I looked at this: [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8238456/9481613)
But it does not really say anything different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first iteration of the loop following the `//put base case in dict` comment `i` is `0`.

You're then attempting to access `T[i-1][j]`, which is the equivalent of `T[-1][j]`.

Because `T` doesn't have a `-1` index, `T[-1]` resolves to `undefined`, upon which you attempt to access index `[j]` and you get the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I put a row of 0's on paper and forgot.