# Why am I getting ".at" is not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to index an array with `[]` but I'm trying to display an item from an array based on its index using `Array.at()` method as described here [MDN Docs - `Array.at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: arr1.at is not a function

I double-checked it, and everything is ok, however I don't know what's going wrong.

**Here is my code:**

```js
const arr1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

const res = arr1.at(2);
console.log(res);
```

**Note**: This is different than the proposed duplicate of [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8238456).  That question is about methods for accessing an array, this question is why a new API for doing so is unavailable and how to rectify that.

Comment: There is no function `at` on arrays. Try array index instead i.e. `arr1[2]`

Comment: @decpk first of all why you directly devoted this question? Please don't do that and demotivate beginners. Moreover its exist you can check here "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at"

Comment: @safinghoghabori evidently `.at()` doesn't exist in your environment. You *are* getting an error. `.at()` is extremenly new - it's still [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) (Stage 3), not even added to [the latest draft of the ES specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object). So, environments that support it are ***very*** few. You can see the table at the bottom of the page.

Comment: yes maybe but i was referring MDN docs and I encounter that method

Comment: @VLAZ that looks like it could be an answer.

Comment: At is better for accessing the last value - It's coming soon - https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.at

Comment: @CertainPerformance, please re-review.  This question is not a dupe of the listed question

Comment: @SafinGhoghabori Yes, you are referencing the docs. But did you also check the browser compatiblitity table? It says for instance Chrome >= 92 or nodeJs >= 16.6. Does your environment meet this requirement? Probably not ...

Comment: Closely related: [Property "at" does not exist on Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69869479/1048572) in TypeScript, and [Downsides of using `array.at(index)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70456996/1048572)

Comment: I only found this error on Safari

Comment: We have a CI test pipeline that uses node 14.x and it just so seems that it should be 16.6.x+ See answers below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you get this message, whatever platform you're running the code on does not support the method yet. It's quite new - while the most recent versions of most browsers [support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility), anything before 2021 definitely won't. This method was [only very recently](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.at) signed off on (end of August 2021) and incorporated into the official specification, so it won't exist in older environments. Either upgrade your environment, or add a polyfill.

Per the proposal document, a "rough polyfill" that should be standards-compliant for most cases is:

```
function at(n) {
    // ToInteger() abstract op
    n = Math.trunc(n) || 0;
    // Allow negative indexing from the end
    if (n < 0) n += this.length;
    // OOB access is guaranteed to return undefined
    if (n < 0 || n >= this.length) return undefined;
    // Otherwise, this is just normal property access
    return this[n];
}

const TypedArray = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(Int8Array);
for (const C of [Array, String, TypedArray]) {
    Object.defineProperty(C.prototype, "at",
                          { value: at,
                            writable: true,
                            enumerable: false,
                            configurable: true });
}
```

Simply run that before trying to use `.at`, and you should be able to use it, even on older incompatible environments. You can also install [this more exhaustive shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.at) instead if you wish.

Comment: It was working on my home computer but not on the work one and I was scratching my head until I read this. Updated Node and now it works :)

Comment: Excellent solution for when pollyfilling does not work

Answer (score 9):

If you're using node.js then please check the version of node.

It should be greater than **16.6.0.** If not then update the node.js version.

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility) of **Array.prototype.at()**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use the [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) library...

> Modular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for
> ECMAScript up to 2021: promises, symbols, collections, iterators,
> typed arrays, many other features, ECMAScript proposals, some
> cross-platform WHATWG / W3C features and proposals like URL. You can
> load only required features or use it without global namespace
> pollution.

First install it with npm or yarn:

```
npm install core-js
```

or

```
yarn add core-js
```

Then use it in your JS or TS project like this:

```
import 'core-js/features/array/at';

let arr = [];
arr.push(42);
console.log(arr.at(0));
```

*Note that the code above only imports the at method for array. To import all polyfills or a subset:*

```
// polyfill all `core-js` features, including early-stage proposals:
import "core-js";
// or:
import "core-js/features";
// polyfill all actual features - stable ES, web standards and stage 3 ES proposals:
import "core-js/actual";
// polyfill only stable features - ES and web standards:
import "core-js/stable";
// polyfill only stable ES features:
import "core-js/es";
```

Comment: Should work but doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine in Stackoverflow code terminal. Your machine might not support the same due to JS versioning. The method is introduced recently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when using Pipedream. I didn't realize that `at()` wasn't included in the NodeJS version they're using hinted at by Li Ki.

I implemented a similar solution proposed by Bjørnar Hvidsten; however, to get it to work in Pipedream, I simply added the following to the top of my NodeJS code.

```
import 'core-js'
const myArray = [1,2,3]

console.log(typeof myArray.at) // "function"
```

P.S. Referencing specific parts of core-js resulted in errors inside Pipedream, at least how I was trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

this is new function and may or may not be supported by the browser so, this is what you can do

array.at(-1)

can be replace with

array[array.length - 1]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, not in the code but in the test-case where it was throwing an error while trying to run this code. Code was working fine. Had to change the implementation to a different one. Could not find a solution/reason for this specifically.

From:
`nextItem = triggerDateGroup.at(currentRowIndex++);`

To:
`nextItem = triggerDateGroup[currentRowIndex++];`