# Property "at" does not exist on Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

According to [MDN Web Docs `Array.prototype#at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at),  is a valid method. But for some reasons, TypeScript refuses to compile, stating that it does not exist.

```
public at(index: number): V {
  index = Math.floor(index);
  const arr = [...this.values()];
  return arr.at(index);
}
```

Console output from tsc:
[image: Typescript Complains more]

I can't use bracket notation, since the method is meant to be able to handle negative numbers. I've tried lots of things, including setting the `target` in the `tsconfig.json` file to ESNext, ES2021, and ES6 but to no avail. The `lib` option doesn't help either.

json

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./typings",
    "lib": ["ES2021", "ESNext"]
  }
}
```

What can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of TS?

Comment: @Phix `typescript@v4.4.4` according to `npm list -g`.

Comment: It's not part of any official version of JavaScript yet (it's a stage 3 tc9 proposal) so this is the time TypeScript usually starts implementing things.  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40695 seems to be the general issue for it, and there's a PR waiting at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40697, but I guess it's not quite ready yet?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/text with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: "I can't use bracket notation, since the method is meant to be able to handle negative numbers".  If you really need to use this, you could implement it yourself, similarly to the [polyfill for it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method#polyfill).  You might end up wanting to polyfill anyway unless you're 100% sure your target JS engine has it.

Comment: @jcalz Alright, I'll look into the polyfill

Comment: Also remember to look at the "specification" section when reading MDN articles. As [per your link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#specifications), this method is not defined in the ECMAScript specification, but is merely a proposal, so until it's incorporated into the official ES spec, this is not a "valid" method in JS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ah ok didn't see that. I'll look for that next time, thanks!

Comment: `return arr[index];`. This is not Java it is JavaScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Array indexing only supports a small subset of the features of `Array.prototype.at`. For example, `Array.prototype.at` supports indexing from the end. Array indexing on the other hand isn't really "array indexing" at all: it is just property access. I.e. `arr[0]` does technically not return the first element of the array, instead it returns the property of the object with the string key `"0"`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you pointing out the negative indexing. For the positive indices, that they are converted to strings and treated as property property access is not a downside of using `a[i]`. Ultimately that's going to happen even when `Array.prototype.at` is used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> According to [MDN Web Docs `Array.prototype#at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at),  is a valid method.

MDN does not get to decide what is part of TypeScript and what isn't. The TypeScript developers do that.

Whether or not MDN says something is a "valid method" is relevant to Mozilla, and only Mozilla, but has no bearing on TypeScript.

> But for some reasons, TypeScript refuses to compile, stating that it does not exist.

That's because the method doesn't exist in any ECMAScript version supported by TypeScript.

> I've tried lots of things, including setting the `target` in the `tsconfig.json` file to ESNext, ES2021, and ES6 but to no avail.

That's because the method doesn't exist in either [ECMAScript 6](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) or [ECMAScript 2021](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object). It *does* [exist in ES2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.at) (which is what ESNext is at the moment), but it was only [added eight weeks ago](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/2493/commits/3aafa2406c3718044a64da1d64697e3e432e21ef), and thus after TypeScript 4.4 was finalized (and possibly also too late for TypeScript 4.5).

> The `lib` option doesn't help either.

Again, that's because the method *does not exist* in any library version supported by TypeScript at the moment.

Even in the current *main* branch, which is going to become TypeScript 4.6, [`lib/lib.esnext.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.esnext.d.ts#L21-L22) only corresponds to [ECMAScript 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2021.d.ts) + the latest [Internationalization extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.esnext.intl.d.ts).

> What can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

You can wait until the method actually becomes part of a released version of ECMAScript and/or TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Array#at is indeed a new method available only in ESNext or by using a polyfill. If you're using latter, you can just augment global array interface like this:

```
declare global {         
   interface Array<T> {                     
      at(index: number): T;
   }
}
```