# Using Array.at(index) instead of Array[index] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about `Array.at()` method that was introduced [Array.prototype.at() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at). It seems more useful than squared brackets annotation `arr[i]` since there is an option to specify index starting from the end of an array, for example: `arr.at(-1)` which would return the last member of `arr` array. Also, it seems more appropriate for method chaining. Are there any downsides to switching to it?

Comment: I'm curious how it's "more appropriate for method chaining", I don't see a meaningful difference between `foo[n].someFn()` and `foo.at(n).someFn()` (other than the extra characters). Really the only win is `at(-1)` which AFAICT could be folded into square-bracket semantics as well.

Comment: In [proposal-relative-indexing-method repo readme](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) *Possible issues* holds a single item - _might also be web incompatible for reasons yet unknown_. If you want to dive deeper into the problem, there is more info by the link.

Comment: Not really the most useful method ever. The only advantage I see is that your code will be a bit shorter and maybe a bit cleaner. So instead of `arr[length-2]`, you only need to write `arr.at(-2)`.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of disadvantages to it are:

- It's a very new method. Older browsers will not be able to understand your code if you use it, unless you include a polyfill - so [make sure you include one.](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.at).
- On a completely different track, since it's such a new method, I wouldn't be surprised if a substantial number of developers haven't heard about it - using `.at` may confuse some of them (and cause them to have to look it up). Not that this means that you shouldn't use it, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: The second point is actually a positive.

Comment: It may be good *for the developer in question*, who isn't OP and is reading their code, if they're smart enough to look things up, but it may not be a good thing for the *codebase* (at least for the next few months, YMMV) because it arguably very slightly obscures the meaning for those who haven't heard about `.at` yet - and the question sounds like from the perspective of the codebase. Lots of people were confused about arrow functions in 2015, for example.

Comment: Eg, given the choice between dead-simple syntax that everyone understands, and longer, more elaborate syntax that 50% of readers might have to look up first in order to understand, I'd prefer the simple version if the more elaborate version doesn't provide any additional useful functionality for the situation.

Comment: `Lots of people were confused about arrow functions in 2015, for example`. The evidence of many SO questions is that lots of people were still confused about arrow functions in 2021 (and doubtless still are in 2022)!

Comment: Not supported by Internet Explorer, Opera Android and Safari on iOS.

Comment: don't know if related to the question anyway you cannot use it to update array values

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't list it as a disadvantage, but new developers might not understand that `Array.prototype.at()` is for retrieval only.  It can't be used for assignment, as `array[array.length-1]` can.

Answer (score 0):

It is not disadvantage but you must keep in mind that:

- [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is **ONLY ACCESSOR** which mean that you can't use it to reset some value inside array

  > By combining at() with [with()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with), you can both read and write (respectively) an array using negative indices
  >
  > [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#description)
- On the other hand [Array[index]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with) is **BOTH ACCESSOR AND MODIFIER**

Answer (score -1):

Another *disadvantage* that *code* can redefine this function. This may be a security concern

```
Array.prototype.at = () => console.log("");
```

Comment: Then we shouldn't use javascript at all? Everything you do with javascript is re-defineable. Ban all Web APIs!

Comment: @AntoniSilvestrovič First, the text above doesn't imply what you state. And the second, not everything in JavaScript redefined

Comment: Well, not every web api is re-definable, but "everything you do with JavaScript is re-definable". You can make the same statement about a lot of functions in JavaScript that are present in everything that you write with it, at which point we're back to using server-side languages. Let's not forget that the code that can redefine `Array.prototype.at` can also redefine your code. Security concern is not with malicious code modifying `.at` but with the way it got to your browser in the first place. How did it happen that someone can modify your prototypes?

Answer (score -1):

The Array.at() method is under experiment at present and it might get change as developers around the world will test and create loopholes, ofcourse.

Though, you can use the polyfill and things get easy for you as any future change on the experiment will not affect your code and it will not break apart.

Also, the method might work with both () and [] which is a quite confusing thing. It is mentioned in the mozilla official docs as: This is not to suggest there is anything wrong with using the square bracket notation.

So, it is not recommendable to use array.at now.

[image]

Comment: *"is under experiment at present"* .. huh? Where did you get that from?

Answer (score -1):

Only improvements I think. Similar to python code JS can now view a array with index -1 to indicate the last element.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[a.length-1] # 3
```

or

```
a.at(-1) #3
```