# How to setState for nested array of object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

This is the object, lets say I'm gonna add something inside list: [], how can I do that? I know like we can do it using the prevList callback but I'm kind of confused to map through it.

```
const [boardlist, setBoardlist] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      boardName: "home work",
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          header: "Stuff to do",
          list: [
            {
              id: 1,
              taskTitle: "working from home",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          header: "In Progress",
          list: [],
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          header: "Done",
          list: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: If navigating through this data structure is an issue, see: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1218980)

Comment: Specifically for arrays in state: [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1218980)

Comment: Ya saw it, but I kinda still confused with the array I have, if I could get little bit help, it will really helpful.

Comment: You should include a clear use-case, what you have done to try and make it work ([mcve]) and what's not working.

Comment: The problem is, when I use spread operators, it’s copies all the previous data, I’m not too sure to access into the particular index or object.

Comment: It really depends on how you identify the object you want to update. [By index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8238456/1218980)? [By id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/1218980)?

Comment: Ok let’s say I’m gonna add something into the object “list: []”, how do I remain all the previous data and only update the “list:”?

Comment: Since your state is an array and it seems you want to update a property of the first object within that state, take a look at: [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28121272/1218980).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about make a copy of the state and just push using the bracket notation and dot notation to reach the element that you need to change?

```
const boardlistCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(boardlist));
boardlistCopy[0].data[1].list.push({id: 2, task: "studying React"});
setBoardlist(boardlistCopy);
```