# How to return array element based on input index location

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to return the teacher's name based on what classroom the students name is in.
teacher[0] is responsible for rooms[0] and teacher[1] is responsible for rooms[1] and so on.

```
let teachers = ["Arrington", "Kincart", "Alberts", "Pickett"]
```

```
let rooms = [
  ["Andy", "Rodolfo", "Lynn", "Talia"],
  ["Al", "Ross", "Jorge", "Dante"],
  ["Nick", "Kim", "Jasmine", "Dorothy"],
  ["Adam", "Grayson", "Aliyah", "Alexa"]
]
```

```
let whichTeacher = (student) => {
    return rooms.findIndex(row => row.indexOf(student) !== - 1)
    
}


console.log(`The teacher who has Jorge is ${whichTeacher("Jorge")}.`)
console.log(`The teacher who has Alexa is ${whichTeacher("Alexa")}.`)
```

the current output is

```
The teacher who has Jorge is 1.
The teacher who has Alexa is 3.
```

so I know im close but I cant figure out how to output the teachers name instead of its index number.

Comment: I think you can just do `teachers[whichTeacher("Jorge")}]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value at a specific index of array In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238456/how-to-get-value-at-a-specific-index-of-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use your teachers array. By indexing it you can achieve what you want:

```js
let teachers = ["Arrington", "Kincart", "Alberts", "Pickett"]


let rooms = [
  ["Andy", "Rodolfo", "Lynn", "Talia"],
  ["Al", "Ross", "Jorge", "Dante"],
  ["Nick", "Kim", "Jasmine", "Dorothy"],
  ["Adam", "Grayson", "Aliyah", "Alexa"]
]

let whichTeacher = (student) => {
    return teachers[rooms.findIndex(row => row.indexOf(student) !== - 1)]
    //             ^ use the found index to index the teachers array
}


console.log(`The teacher who has Jorge is ${whichTeacher("Jorge")}.`)
console.log(`The teacher who has Alexa is ${whichTeacher("Alexa")}.`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the teacher at this index of the `teachers` array :

```js
const teachers = ["Arrington", "Kincart", "Alberts", "Pickett"]
const rooms = [
  ["Andy", "Rodolfo", "Lynn", "Talia"],
  ["Al", "Ross", "Jorge", "Dante"],
  ["Nick", "Kim", "Jasmine", "Dorothy"],
  ["Adam", "Grayson", "Aliyah", "Alexa"]
]
const whichTeacher = student => teachers[ rooms.findIndex(row => row.includes(student)) ]


console.log(`The teacher who has Jorge is ${ whichTeacher("Jorge") }.`)
console.log(`The teacher who has Alexa is ${ whichTeacher("Alexa") }.`)
```

(btw : prefer using `const` instead of `let` whenever its possible (even more for arrow functions) and use the built-ins when you can (like `Array.prototype.includes` instead of `array.indexOf(...) != -1`) for clarity and sometimes for performances)